# How can I extend an object in Clojurescript?

Tags: clojurescript

I do not want to extend a class, just a one instance of a class with a protocol. is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing sounds like the current proposal for `specify!` ([JIRA](http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJS-414) and [Design Document](http://dev.clojure.org/display/design/specify+i.e.+reify+for+instances)). So, it is currently not possible to extend a single instance with a protocol.